# Python: set python2 as the default after installing python 3 with anacoda3

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

I used anaconda3 for a python3 install. And now it's my default python:

```
$ which python
/home/xy/anaconda3/bin/python
$ which python3
/home/xy/anaconda3/bin/python
```

But I need python2 as my default python.

```
$ which python2
/usr/bin/python2
```

I tried to edit my .bashrc shown below,

```
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/xy/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/nu
ll)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/xy/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/xy/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/xy/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

By change the line of export PATH... to

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/xy/anaconda3/bin"
```

It didn't change anything.

How should I set python2 back as the default?

Comment: Obligatory: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: I am not happy with the comments here: IMO, this can be solved cleanly, by using `conda init <shell>`, removing anaconda3/bin from `PATH` and setting ´conda config --set auto_activate_base False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to go forward is to do following changes:

1) Edit your `~/.bashrc` and do following modifications

Keep this block. Do not edit it. If you already deleted it, you can recreate it by typing `conda init bash`.

```
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/xy/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/nu
ll)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/xy/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/xy/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/xy/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

2) Make sure you `/home/xy/anaconda3/bin` is not added to PATH outside of this block. If so, delete those.

3) Call `conda config --set auto_activate_base False` in your shell

From now on, you have to activate the anaconda environment manually with `conda activate base`. If you do not call this, you will default back to your system python.